Canopen system simulation without master
I would like to build a simulation for canopen system that consist of slave nodes, and than connect this system to a master that we have implemented in rust.
For this purpose I am using ROS2_canopen package (any better ideas?)
I have managed to run "fake_slaves" that respond to nmt messages, but I need the simulation to use cia402, so I try to launch "canopen_tests > cia402_system" but that system already has a master in it, and can messages are already exchanged on startup which messes up communication with my master.
Is there a way to launch CIA402_system without the master?
Or is there a better solution for my problem?
UPDATE:
I have managed to do that by commenting out certain parts inside device container. https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros2_canopen/blob/master/canopen_core/src/device_container.cpp
But I also had to comment out the launch of Proxy driver (inside https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros2_canopen/blob/master/canopen_402_driver/include/canopen_402_driver/node_interfaces/node_canopen_402_driver_impl.hpp). This I might need to undo.
Now I'm gonna try and find the way to send the commands from 'fake_slave' to 'cia402_driver', so that the state of dcf file is updated when homing is started.

Take a look at this file https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros2_canopen/blob/master/canopen_fake_slaves/launch/cia402_slave.launch.py. it Basically Shows how to launch a single cia402 slave.

Thank you for your answer!
(I might be wrong on things, but I try to lay down my reasoning)
I have already tried this solution, unfortunately it does not include the functionality that is part of https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros2_canopen/tree/master/canopen_402_driver
Therefore I have tried to launch the control manager that includes the drivers. I modify this file: https://github.com/ros-industrial/ros2_canopen/blob/master/canopen_tests/launch/cia402_system.launch.py
However, I cannot figure out how to run the device manager without the master driver.

I want only the slave cia402 nodes to be there. Otherwise it messes the communication with the master that I have implemented (outside of ROS)

Thank you in advance for your answer, I appreciate all the help :) .
